# Switching between fragments with a button in default Navigation Drawer template of Android Studio

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, drawer

I'm using default Navigation Drawer in Android Studio, and I added two fragments for first two button in navigation drawer. Everything works fine and I can switch between these fragments from drawer menu.

But I want to have a simple button in first fragment that clicking on it take me to second fragment. Clicking on such button opens second fragment but it seems to overlap whole screen and disappear the navigation view.

These are my project's codes:

***MainActivity.java :***

```
package com.example.arantik.test4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Fragment fragment=null;

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragment=new Fragment_1();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fragment=new Fragment_2();
        }

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

***activity_main.xml :***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

***content_main.xml :***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.arantik.test4.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainFrame">
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

***Fragment_1.java :***

```
package com.example.arantik.test4;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1_layout, container, false);

        Button button=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                Fragment_2 fragment_2=new Fragment_2();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment_2);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

***fragmen_1_layout.xml :***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="First Fragment"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="click"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

***Fragment_2.java :***

```
package com.example.arantik.test4;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment_2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2_layout, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

***fragmen_2_layout.xml :***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ff00">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="Second Fragment"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've not changed other Java or XML codes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a public method to `MainActivity`, cast `getActivity()` to `MainActivity` in your fragment, and then you can invoke the method. You can also use `interface`, refer [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Can you please explain more about casting? I am new to android.

Comment: Sorry, I think it's not a good idea to get FragmentManager in fragment now. The following may be a better way. [gist](https://gist.github.com/z-jp/2abc6a08f80236bc72dba27ba1c3947b)